# Use the Rayleigh Ritz method to obtain a two-element quadratic approximation to the BVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, numerical-methods

> Use the Ritz method to obtain a two element quadratic approximation to the boundary value problem, $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+u=-x,\quad0<x<1,u(0)=u(1)=0$$

I try to get the weak form,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+u&=-x\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dx} \right)+u&=-x\\
\int_0^1 \left[\hat{u}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)+\hat{u}u\right]dx&=-\int_0^1 \hat{u}x\:dx\\
-\int_0^1 \left[ \frac{d\hat{u}}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}+\hat{u}u\right]dx&=-\int_0^1 \hat{u}x\:dx
\end{align}
$$

Now, the functional become,

$$I[u]=-\int_0^1 \left[ \left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2+u^2\right]dx+\int_0^1 ux\:dx$$

To find an approximation of the minimizer of $I[u]$, $$u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j \phi_j(x)$$

Taking quadratic approximation, $$u(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$$ I didn't get what they mean by two element for Rayleigh Ritz method? Wasn't that use for finite element method?

Applying boundary condition we get, $$u(x)=c_1(x-x^2)$$

Then $\frac{dI}{dc_1}=0$ implies $c_1=\frac{5}{44}$. Then $u(x)=\frac{5}{44}(x-x^2)$

Is my approach being correct? I was reading Finite Element Method and [Rayleigh-Ritz Method](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat461/spr10/lecture27.pdf) to solve boundary value problem. These two methods seem to be very similar like we need to get weak form, choose trial functions and then solve the functional by constructing system of equation.

- What's the true difference between Finite Element method and Rayleigh-Ritz Method?

**I was looking for some resources where I can get many working boundary value problems to get understand how to choose the trial solution for Rayleigh Ritz method.**